# Prove that second order linear differential equation's solution is limited

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a second order linear differential equation:
$$x''+xe^t=0$$
It is clear that every its solution $x(t)$ oscillates and it can be proven that the distance between closest zeros of the function decreases. Though I still don't get how to prove that:
$$\text{ If }b_n=\max\limits_{t\in[t_{n}; \ t_{n+1}]}|x(t)|, \text{ then }\ b_1>b_2>b_3>\dots$$
where $\{t_n\}$ is a sequence of zeros of the function $x(t)$.

Thanks in forward and sorry if dublicating (I couldn't find anything).

Comment: What has the title to do with the question? What does "limited" mean?

Comment: As I mentioned, the function oscillates, and it's tops and bottoms cannot grow ulimitedly. We are tasked to prove that the amplitude decreases, actually

Comment: Ok, sorry, it is just that "limited" made me think that you are content with showing that the function is bounded.

Comment: It actually is, but from both sides. Sorry for that)

Answer (score 2):

This not an answer to the question, but a comment too long to be put in the comment section.

Also, this is a discussion about the validity of the question if no boundary condition is specified.

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+x(t)e^t=0 \tag 1$$
Change of variable : $\theta=ae^{bt}\quad\to\quad d\theta=b\theta\:dt$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=b\theta\frac{dx}{d\theta}$

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(b\theta\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\left(b\theta\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}+b\frac{dx}{d\theta} \right) b\theta=b^2\theta^2\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}+b^2\theta\frac{dx}{d\theta}$
$$b^2\theta^2\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}+b^2\theta\frac{dx}{d\theta}+x\frac{\theta^{1/b}}{a^{1/b}}=0$$
$$\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}+\frac{1}{\theta}\frac{dx}{d\theta}+\frac{\theta^{(1/b)-2}}{b^2a^{1/b}}x(\theta)=0$$
To transform Eq.$(1)$ to a Bessel equation, we just have to set $b=\frac12$ and $b^2a^{1/b}=1$, thus $a=2$ :
$$\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}+\frac{1}{\theta}\frac{dx}{d\theta}+x(\theta)=0 \tag 2$$
The general solution is : $\quad x(\theta)=c_1J_0(\theta)+c_2Y_0(\theta)$

where $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are the Bessel functions of first and second kind and order $0$.
$$x(t)=c_1J_0(2e^{t/2})+c_2Y_0(2e^{t/2})$$
Of course, if we consider independently $J_0(X)$ and $Y_0(X)$, the roots are well defined. There is a lot of studies about the roots of the Bessel functions, where one could find pertinent material to answer to the question which, then, is a well-asked question.

But if no boundary condition is specified, $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be any constants and the roots of $x(t)$ can be any values (depending on $c_1$ and $c_2$). I wonder if the question raised could be answered on a general manner in those non-specific conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your participation! I'got that result via Wolfram, and you've shown me the way. However I'm sure that touching $J_0$ and $Y_0$ is unnecessary for solution, as they're rather complicated